# compare strings on Bash does not works

Tags: bash, shell

is this correct?

```
    existed_design_document=$(curl "Administrator:*******@couchbase:8092/$MY_APP_DB_BUCKET/_design/dev_$environment" | jq '.error ')

    echo "$existed_design_document"
    if [ "$existed_design_document" == "not_found" ]
       then
         echo "The document design does not exist"
    fi
```

I see in the echo the value "not_found" but still I´m not getting into the if. Any idea why?

Comment: what's the output of `declare -p existed_design_document` or `printf '%q\n' "$existed_design_document"`? Like so you'll see if there are funny characters in your variable. `echo` is not reliable for this kind of inspections.

Comment: `bash` allows `==` inside `[...]`, but it's good to get in the habit of using `=` instead (or use `[[ ... == ... ]]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try with this baby example:

```
$ a=$(echo '{"error": "not_found"}' | jq .error)
```

I get:

```
$ declare -p a
declare -- a="\"not_found\""
```

So the quotes are also in the output of `jq`. So you need this:

```
if [[ $existed_design_document = "\"not_found\"" ]]
```

---

As [@EtanReisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523) points out (thanks!): `jq` has the `-r` flag:

```
       With  this  option, if the filter´s result is a string then it will
       be written directly to standard output rather than being  formatted
       as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq fil‐
       ters talk to non-JSON-based systems.
```

So you should even do this:

```
existed_design_document=$(curl "Administrator:*******@couchbase:8092/$MY_APP_DB_BUCKET/_design/dev_$environment" | jq -r .error)
echo "$existed_design_document"
if [[ $existed_design_document = "not_found" ]; then
     echo "The document design does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: The `jq` flag `-r` would also be useful here.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh cool! (I didn't even read `jq`'s man page, just answered from obvious facts… but will edit the answer).

Answer (score 0):

One more reliable solution that is not affected by quotes, but only looks for a given string is based on regex. This will match your text:

```sh
if [[ $existed_design_document =~ not_found ]]; then
     echo "The document design does not exist"
fi
```

That will match anything that contain not_found, so, it is more flexible, but also could match some UN-expected strings. It is a trade-off between flexibility and precision.